# Java parse XML response by using DOM

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom

I want to catch the response of the following URL:

http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&term=ACE+OR+%28Adverse+AND+Childhood+AND+Experiences%29

I have the following code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
org.w3c.dom.Document doc = db.parse(new URL("http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&term=ACE+OR+%28Adverse+AND+Childhood+AND+Experiences%29").openStream());
```

When I do:

```
System.out.println ("Root element: " + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
```

I do get:

`Root element: eSearchResult`

which is correct, but I don't know hot to access the value in the first "Count" node and this does not work:

```
String count = doc.getFirstChild().getChildNodes().item(0).getTextContent();
```

Comment: show the structure of you xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
System.out.println ("First Count Text: " + doc.getElementsByTagName("Count").item(0).getTextContent());
```

or,

```
doc.getDocumentElement().getFirstChild().getTextContent();
```